# How to set timer to automatically set a field value if not updated within 15 minutes in rails from the time of creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs

I have a rails app in which an order is assigned to a vendor to accept or reject the order which is stored as status in the order assignment table by that vendor for that particular order. If the order is not accepted or rejected by the vendor within 15 minutes, then the order is supposed to be auto-rejected i.e the status is updated to rejected automatically for that vendor and stored into the table.How do I achieve this task?

```
Estamps::Order

has_many :order_assignments
belongs_to :vendor

Estamps::Vendor

has_many :order_assignments
has_many :orders

Estamps::OrderAssignment 

belongs_to :vendor, class_name: 'Estamps::Vendor'
belongs_to :order, class_name: 'Estamps::Order'
```

Schema for OrderAssignment table:

```
  t.string   "status"
  t.integer  "vendor_id"
  t.integer  "order_id
```

After assigning an order to a vendor, the vendor should update the status as accepted, rejected. If not updated for any assigned order within 15 minutes, the status should be set to rejected automatically. This should happen for any assigned order. Can Anyone help me achieve this? I am a newbie with rails here.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are correct that it's a good fit for a queue, but note that Rails has exposed a nice API on top of all queues called activejob: 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

All you have to do is choose a job queue (popular choices: sidekiq, resque, delayed_job). Note that delayed_job will be the easiest to deploy since it has no extra dependencies such as redis (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

After installing for example delayed_job all you have left to do is enqueue a job after the creation of order assignment that checks it's status after 15 minutes, like so:

```
 Estamps::OrderAssignment 
 after_create :enqueue_check_status 

 def enqueue_check_status 
     #this is activejob syntax to enqueue a job at a later time
     OrderStatusJob.set(wait: 15.minutes).perform_later(self.id)
 end

 #the rails way to define a job class
class OrderStatusJobJob < ApplicationJob
   queue_as :default

   def perform(order_assignment_id)
      order_assignment = OrderAssignment.find(order_assignment_id)
      if order_assignment.status != true 
        order_assignment.update_attribute('status', 'REJECTED')
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Note that you could define the after_create callback on Order model in a similar manner, it might even make more sense for your needs

Comment: The thing is, I do not need to destroy the order, just update the status for the order in the order assignment status as "REJECTED". Secondly, the wait method in the model, will it cause the entire app to wait, or will it continue creating orders and assigning and setting their status or perform any other task without interruption, but will perform the said operation for that particular order_assignment record after 15 minutes? Sorry if the question seems silly, just want to understand the know-how.

Comment: It won't cause the entire app to wait, that's exactly the point of queues and background workers , everything happens on the background, meaning usually there's a different process running that handles all the jobs , so it has no effect on your main rails app (other than sharing the same db but thats usually ok). There should be zero problem changing the code I wrote to change the status to REJECTED(just call update_attribute instead of destroy), let me know if you're having a problem there.

Comment: The Job does is not updating the status. If I call OrderStatusJob.set(wait: 15.minutes).perform_now(id) on console it works.But otherwise , it does not run. I am using resque scheduler. Am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: Should be no difference between console to dev (they both go to the same resque configuration), Perhaps you're not actually calling the perform_later code in dev? try to verify the code actually happens.

Comment: after_create :enqueue_check_status 

    def enqueue_check_status 
       AutoRejectionJob.set(wait: 2.minutes).perform_later(self.id)
    end

Comment: class AutoRejectionJob < ActiveJob::Base
 queue_as :auto_rejection

 def perform(order_assignment_id)
  order_assignment = Estamps::OrderAssignment.find(order_assignment_id) 
  if order_assignment 
            if order_assignment.status_id == 1 
                 order_assignment.update_attribute('status_id', '3')
                 order_assignment.save!
             end  
     end
    end
end

Comment: @Joel_blum.The above two is the code just like you've shown. The problem still persists. After two minutes the status is not updated.

Comment: I have been still struggling with this issue.OrderStatusJob.set(wait: 15.minutes).perform_later(self.id) does not seem to work with the wait part.If I just run OrderStatusJob.perform_later(self.id) then the code works. Otherwise for some reason the code with the set wait part does not works, it is just enqueued to be resqued for 15 minutes, but the status does not gets updated after 15 minutes. Need more suggestions from you

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using scheduler like sidekiq or resque. This will do these actions in the background and will not bother the controller. But the problem with this is that we need redis server to make this work. Anyway check out the [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).